# rangeError :maximum call stack exceeded in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to use the ngRoute module, but I get errors thrown ..
By the way I have already downloaded the ngRoute module .

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

myApp.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: "angular.html",
      controller: "mainCtrl"
    })
    .when('/second', {

      templateUrl: "second.html",
      controller: "mainCtrl"
    })

    .when('/main', {
      templateUrl: "main.html",
      controller: "mainCtrl"
    })

}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried following the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: @alok yes i have ..or am i missing something in the code?